# OPUS Audio codec encoding for iPhone

Tags: audio, voip, codec

Can the recently released OPUS Audio codec (libopus?) be compiled to run on mobile devices (read iPhone/Android)?

I've searched and came to the conclusion that te documentation states it runs on ARM devices but after trying to compile the library it always fails when cross-compiling.

Am I mistaken or there is no support for such devices tat this time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one thing I was missing was the Host, it turned out to be 'arm-apple-darwin' now it is working correctly.

```
./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it builds directly on Xcode. No need to use cross compilers. I am compiling it for iOS.

Comment: I found out that my sources were broken and the errors i was getting were not related to the opus build itself.

Comment: Hi superg, Can you please let me know how you achieved it, cause am stuck with the same thing from past 3 days

Comment: @huxia with this I have the problem that at some point the build script returns "checking whether the C compiler works... no" and "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables". Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: @DeveloBär No. For me everything works fine, I guess there may be something wrong with your xcode version/configuration?